# Флешка. Место занято, но система не видит файлы

Tags: windows, файлы, файловая-система

Имеется флешка на 8ГБ. Туда была закачана музыка. Ранее, насколько я помню, всё было годно. Прошло с того времени год (+-), её, вроде бы, никто особо и не трогал. Однак сейчас такая ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как быть?

Comment: 1) Проверьте антивирусом. 2) в на стройках папки выберите показ скрытых файлов. 3) просто отформатируйте

Comment: проверил др.вебом - проблем нет. показ скрытых файлов - выбран. форматировать - не хотелось бы.

Comment: Сними дамп с помощью ddrescue или любой прогой для восстановления инфы и потом уже отформатируй.

Comment: А если "прогнать" какой- нибудь программой для восстановления удалённых файлов? Суть вопроса не совсем ясна: если музыка не нужна, просто форматнуть, если нужна — попробовать первый вариант.

Comment: может монтирование флэшки (mount) не тот? такое может возникать если использовалась флэшка при работе с unix системами потом windows или наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Не видны только в проводнике?

Вариант 1: поставить Far manager  - он показывает любые скрытые файлы без проблем.

Вариант 2  - если в Far файлы видны не будут - пройтись по флэшке программой GetDataBack - она для восстановления файлов - не редко спасает. есть portable версии